# Should HANDLE returned by CreateEvent be disposed?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, handle

I was inspecting someone's code and I saw this:

```
template<typename Data>
class ConcurrentQueue {

    private:
        HANDLE dataPushEvent;
        // More Private Members...

    public:
        ConcurrentQueue() {
            dataPushEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
        }

    // Public Methods...

};
```

As you can see, there is no destructor on this class, and the `dataPushEvent` is not explicitly freed anywhere in this class. Since it's a private member, it cannot be accesed externally, so I was thinking this'd probably create a memory leak.

Unless this handle is not supposed to be disposed.

I'm new to C++ and Windows programming. As far as I'm concerned, `HANDLE` is a `void *`, and as all pointers, its reference should be released when we are done using it.

Am I right?

Comment: `CloseHandle()` should be called on `dataPushEvent` if you wish to release it prior to process termination.

Comment: That's `HANDLE`, right?

Comment: @AlexK. Oh I see! Should I try to manually `delete` the pointer if `CloseHandle()` fails?

Comment: `HANDLE` is of type `void*`, but is not actually a pointer. It doesn't point to anything and can't be dereferenced. You can't release a handle like a pointer (don't try to `delete` it).

Comment: @MatiCicero No, but you should assert on the return value from `CloseHandle()` -- if it fails then you probably have a bug and/or memory corruption and you want the program to crash spectacularly so that you know there is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no destructor, then yes, the handle is leaked.  There should be a destructor calling [`CloseHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx) to destroy the event.

As a side note, the class should also delete (C++11) or make inaccessible (C++03) the copy constructor and copy assignment operators, since the compiler-generated defaults will not make sense -- they are likely to copy the queued data, but still reference the same event handle, causing multiple seemingly-independent queues to share an event for no good reason. And when you do implement the destructor, the default copy implementation will be even worse because once one copy gets destructed it will destroy the event handle still in use by all of the other copies!

In C++11, you can implement the move-constructor and the move-assignment operators, but you'll have to tweak your destructor to account for the fact that the handle might have been moved to another object so that it doesn't call `CloseHandle()`.

Comment: Thanks for the C++11 and C++03 tip!! I don't have access to C++11 so I guess I'd have to make them private!

Comment: @MatiCicero Yup, declare them as private and *don't implement them*. (If you use them accidentally in a context in which they are visible, you want to get a link-time error so you know that you accidentally used them.)

Comment: Also worth noting: If the constructor contains code after the `CreateEvent` call that can throw exceptions, you still leak the `HANDLE`, since the destructor won't run. It's probably not a bad idea to have an RAII wrapper exclusively for the Event object.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, very good point. If that object is made non-copyable (and also movable, in C++11) then `ConcurrentQueue` will automatically become non-copyable and/or movable, too, and a custom destructor won't be necessary!